# Redirecting output depending on grep regex

Tags: shell, grep, io-redirection, tee

I am using `gradle run` to start a REST server. The output of the REST server looks like this:

```
XXX.XXX.XX.XXX - <moreinfo>
randomtext
randomtext
XXX.XXX.XX.XXX - <moreinfo>
XXX.XXX.XX.XXX - <moreinfo>
randomtext
XXX.XXX.XX.XXX - <moreinfo>
```

`XXX.XXX.XX.XXX` here is an IP address, randomtext are error messages. All output is directed to stdout, sadly.

How can I direct all lines starting with an IP address to a file called `err.log` and every other line to `all.log`?

Unfortunately, `gradle run` can only be started once and doesn't stop, since it is a REST server.

Maybe use a `tee` , `grep` combination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Bash, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) with tee:

```
tee >(grep XXX > err.log) | grep -v XXX > all.log
```

This will put all lines matching XXX into `err.log`, and all lines into `all.log`. `>( ... )` creates the process in the parentheses and connects its standard output to a pipe. This works in [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html) and other modern shells too.

You can also use the `pee` command from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
pee "grep XXX > err.log" "grep -v XXX > all.log"
```

`pee` redirects standard input to multiple commands ("tee for pipes").

A further alternative is with awk:

```
awk '{ if (/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/) { print > "err.log" } else { print > "all.log" } }'
```

That just tests every line against the expression and writes the whole thing into `err.log` if it matches and `all.log` if it doesn't.

The awk regular expression is suitable for `grep -E` too (although it does match some bad addresses — `999.0.0.0` and so on — but that probably isn't a problem).

Comment: Hmm `err.log` is empty and all output is redirected to `all.log` using the `tee` command above.

Comment: Check that your regular expression is actually matching the right lines — if `err.log` exists at all then the command ran but nothing came out. `grep -E` with the expression used in the awk command ought to match, or it does here.

Comment: Ah ok I got it. Can you modify your question so that `all.log` doesn't contain the matched lines in the grep expression?

Comment: Done — wasn't sure which one you wanted, so I had both.

Comment: Oh darn sorry, it worked. I overwrote `all.log` and `err.log` with an old command. Sorry for the confusion.

Thanks, you're awesome :))!!

Comment: Hmm somehow I only get 4096 bytes of output, then it breaks and no output is stored anymore. Why is that?

Comment: Also your `awk` line results in `err.log` being empty and `all.log` containing every line of input. :(

Comment: My best guess for awk is again that the regular expression isn't matching your data - it works here if I put `127.0.0.1` in. Find what the right pattern for your real data is, then substitute that in. 4096 sounds like a (small) pipe buffer size, which you might be able to `ulimit` bigger, although I'm still surprised it fills up. I've run several MB through it here with no trouble.

Comment: Does it have to do anything with the `--posix` or `--re-interval` flags? I've seen other old threads mentioning them to use POSIX standard syntax. But on according to my `man awk`, these flags are not recognized anymore. See here: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_5.html .

I tried using your `awk` command above with the same regex and it's weird that it doesn't work. How do I `ulimit` the pipe buffer for this command only? /^[0-9]3/, /^[0-9]+/, /^[0-9].*/ works, other not.

Comment: I have been using gawk without any additional flags. You can use ulimit inside a `( )` subshell with other commands. I am surprised it would break for that, though, so it might be something else (maybe Gradle-specific?).

Comment: yeah I guess so. I think I should use a `while read line; do ... done < gradle run` and try it that way. Thanks for your help though. Nice info about moreutils (funny name:)).

Comment: Ok I got it working with `while read line...`. It's weird that I am having these bugs. I'd really like to know an answer for that. Well, your solution is all in all right :).

Comment: For the `grep` variant, I  would use a `--line-buffered` flag, such that you won't have to wait as long for the lines showing up in the log.

Answer (score 4):

So, it looks like `gradle run` doesn't comply with `tee`, `pee`, `grep` and io-redirection. It always stops reading after 4096 bytes.

To circumvent this issue, I `read` each line of `gradle run`. I didn't test it yet, but I guess that reading a line that is over 4k characters long will also fail.

Anyway, here is the code to solve my question specifically:

```
#!/bin/bash
STDOUTLOG="/log/stdout.txt"
STDERRLOG="/log/stderr.txt"
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}.* ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "$STDERRLOG" && continue
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "$STDOUTLOG"
done < <(gradle run)
```

Comment: You should use `read -r line` and `printf '%s\n' "$line"` to avoid some [edge](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) [cases](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) breaking things.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Thank you! I modified the answer accordingly :).